# The modular curve $X(1)$ has one cusp

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'd like to know why $X(1)$ has only one cusp. In particular, I'd like to know why the orbit space of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\infty$ via $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}(m/n)=(am+bn)/(cn+dn)$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\infty = a/c$ has only one element. It's not clear to me that if I pick any rational number $r/s$ that I can find an invertible matrix $A$ with determinant $1$ such that $A(m/n)=r/s$.

Comment: Have you verified the action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\infty$ as given in the question is a well-defined group action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\frac mn\in\Bbb Q$, $n\not=0$. WLOG, suppose $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Then there are integer $x,y$ such that $xm+yn=1$. You can compute such a pair by [the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Hence,
$\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ -n & m \end{pmatrix}\in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ -n & m \end{pmatrix}(m/n)=(xm+yn)/(-nm+mn)=\frac 10=\infty$$

That means, $\frac mn$ is in the same orbit as $\infty$. Since $m,n\not=0$ are arbitrary integers, there is only one orbit of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a more general version of this that I find enlightening.

If $K$ is an arbitrary field, then the group $SL(2,K)$ acts on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ just like for $K = \mathbb{Q}$.  This is the same as the action of $SL(2,K)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ -- just regard $K$ as the set of elements that in homogeneous coordinates equal $[x,1]$, and $\infty$ is the point $[1,0]$.

Now assume that $K$ is an algebraic number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$.  Then it turns out that the number of orbits of $SL(2,\mathcal{O})$ acting on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ is the same as the class number of $\mathcal{O}$.  Thus there is one orbit if and only if $\mathcal{O}$ has unique factorization (like $\mathbb{Z}$), and more generally the number of orbits is a numerical measure of the failure of unique factorization.

For a nice discussion of this and its proof, see [these](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/SL2classno.pdf) notes by Keith Conrad.